# JQuery and using $(this) to access attributes

Tags: jquery, this

Hi I am developing a calculator. At the moment I am stuck... I am using the jquery on(click) function so when a number gets pressed I can try to print it to the screen. All numbers have the same digit class so I am using $(".digit").on("click", function ());

There are also id's and a value for each number, but I am struggling to use the 'this' variable to access the attribute. Please see snippet below.

```
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="screen"></div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="clear" onclick="clear()">C</button>
            <button class="digit" id="1" value="1">1</button>
            <button class="digit" id="2" value="2">2</button>
            <button class="digit" id="3" value="3">3</button>
            <button class="digit" id="4" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="digit" id="5" value="5">5</button>
        </div>
   </div>

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".digit").on("click", function () {
        $("#screen").append($("this").attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are there quotes arround "this"?

Comment: `this` shouldn't be a string.

Comment: oh, problem solved then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("this").attr("value")
```

to this:

```
$(this).val()
```